# how to login to ftp from vb script

Tags: vbscript, ftp

I am trying to login to an FTP server from VB script and execute some commands.

manually we login to ftp server with:

```
ftp my.server.name
Enter Uname: _
Enter Pwd: _
```

uname and pwd are prompts for the user.  How can I do this from VB script?  if there was a way to login to a ftp server by supplying uname and pwd in the same line then I could just execute one line from the VB script.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a commands file and use that as an input to the FTP

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/rzaiq/rzaiqcrtftpinput.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way

http://www.naterice.com/articles/51

Only problem is you pass credentials in plain text in this script and it presents a potential security risk.